# What is the use of __packed attribute in function arguments

Tags: c, padding, armcc

```
int readint(__packed int *data)
{
    return *data;
}
```

I have seen `__packed` attribute in `struct` declarations to avoid padding. However, what is the benefit of using `__packed` attribute in function arguments.

The [author](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558608745) says that he has used `__packed` to tell the compiler that the integer may possibly not be aligned. What does it means?

**Edit:** Will the following work with `gcc` compiler

```
int readint(__attribute__((packed)) int *data)
{
    return *data;
}
```

Comment: It is important to mention that this is not standard C++ but a compiler specific extension.

Comment: This usage is actually specific to ARM (and, in fact, to a specific ARM C compiler). I've edited the tags to reflect this.

Comment: @duskwuff why is it specific to `arm`, it can be the case with any processor with supports unaligned memory access.

Comment: I edited the tag to 'armcc' ; at least include that one.  Especially, there are macros/extensions like `__packed` for other systems.  It is nice to be up front this question deals with armcc.  I found the tag [arm] misleading, but you can add it back.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `__packed` qualifier is a compiler-specific feature of the `armcc` C compiler, published by ARM. [A full explanation is present in their documentation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0491e/CJAFJHJD.html), but in brief, it indicates that no padding for alignment should be inserted into the qualified object, and that pointers with this qualifier should be accessed as if they might be misaligned. (This may cause slower code to be generated for some processors, so it should not be used gratuitously.)

Note that this is *not* the same as the GCC `packed` attribute, which only applies to `struct` and `union` type definitions.

Comment: We can also use the functions `get_unaligned()` and `put_unaligned()` for doing unaligned reads and writes.